# Can you use a contraction on a compound subject?

Tags: contractions, compound-subjects

For example, it is perfectly normal to write "He's going to the store" but would writing "Bill and she've already left" or similar NOUN and NOUN'xx subjects?

To me, it seems unnatural to do so in writing. But I cant find anything that says its non-standard (or anything on it at all really)

Comment: I'd be inclined to write "Bill and she 'ave already left", if I felt it necessary to represent the manner of speech.

Comment: Or just "Bill and she already left".

Comment: In speech it would be contracted with an extra syllable - /ʃiyəv/ instead of /ʃiv/. In writing we can't indicate that pronunciation difference with an apostrophe followed by a V and a silent E. So avoid it in writing.